# Would this do the same?

Tags: c++

just reading through some C++ books and I'm just wondering if somebody could double check this, would these two pieces of code, both do the same?

```
if (x > 5)
    if(y > 5)
        cout << "something";
else 
    cout <<"something else";
```

---

```
if (x > 5) && (y > 5)
    cout <<"something";
else    
    cout <<"something else";
```

Am I right in thinking these two both do the same thing just differently written, one friend told me they were another told me they weren't so just thought best ask here

Thanks.

Comment: The C++ parser is greedy. You've indented the first block of code incorrectly, causing you to misunderstand it. (Technically, it's the lexer here, but whatever.)

Comment: Your indentation is misleading you I think. In the first example the `else` is actually associated with the inner `if`, not the outer one.

Comment: Surely it'd taken you less time to just test these with various inputs than ask...

Comment: The question makes no sense since the second version is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @bhigg890 The indentation has no purpose, it is for readability. The compiler doesn't care where you indent your conditions, this isn't python, so your indentation only serves to confuse the reader of the code flow in your example

Comment: By the way, the thing to search for to learn more about this "[dangling else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else)". When the compiler sees the `else`, it attaches it to the statement it's currently working on (the second `if`). It doesn't look at other statements it was working on before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two statements are not the same. The former prints nothing at all if `x <= 5`.

The first example also has incorrect indentation (and is a great argument for why you should always include braces). The equivalent with braces is

```
if (x > 5) {
    if (y > 5) {
        cout << "something";
    } else  {
        cout <<"something else";
    }
}
```

This should make it obvious that if `x <= 5` it executes nothing.

Comment: So even doing - if (//something) if(//something) this is not the same as if(//something) && (//something)?

Comment: Yes, so in the case where both expressions are satisfied the output is the same. However, in the scenario where `x<=5`, the first example does not output anything while the second does.

Comment: If you have no `else` then they're equivalent. If you have an `else` then they behave differently.

Comment: @bhigg890 If you are happy with my answer then please mark it as accepted, so your question doesn't stay open.

Answer (score 0):

They do not.

Consider the sample data of x=y=0.
The first snippet will print nothing, while the second one will print "something else".